# Python - Beautiful Soup - How to filter the extracted data for keywords?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the data of websitses using Beautiful Soup and requests, and I've come so far that I've got the data I want but now I want to filter it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "website.com"
keyword = "22222"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('a'):
    for a in article:
        if article.has_attr('data-variant-code'):
            print(article.get("data-variant-code"))
```

Let's say this prints the following:
11111
22222
33333

How can I filter this so it only returns me the "22222"?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, hence 2 completely different answers that are both correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `article.get("data-variant-code")` prints `11111, 22222, 33333`,
you can simply use an `if` statement:

```
for article in soup.find_all('a'):
    for a in article:
        if article.has_attr('data-variant-code'):
           x = article.get("data-variant-code")
           if x == '22222':
               print(x)
```

Comment: probably should've came up with this myself haha, thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome.  If it helped you should accept this as your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the 2nd group of chars in a string delimited by space, then you can split the string using space as delimiter. This will give you a list of strings  then access the 2nd item of the list.

For example:

```
print(article.get("data-variant-code").split(" ")[1])

result:  22222
```